# Playing MediaPlayer across all activities

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an Activity which extends a BaseActivity, in which in the BaseActivity it also creates a Thread in order to play a MediaPlayer throughout all activities in a different Thread, here is my code:

In my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BasedActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beginBGMusic();
  }
}
```

Within my BasedActivity:

```
public class BasedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer BGMusicPlayer;
Thread BGMusic;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

protected void beginBGMusic(){
    BGMusic = new Thread(){

        public void run(){
            BGMusicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.music.mp3);
        }
    };

    BGMusic.start();
  }
}
```

However, the MediaPlayer.create() expects a context, I don't understand how should I set the context if its in a Thread and also in a different class.

Does anyone know how to resolve the problem with my approach?

Thanks!

Comment: If your requirement is use same media player across multiple activity then instead of starting media player inside thread you should create it inside Service and single instance of media player will be accessible across multiple activity.

Comment: Does creating it in a Thread defeat the idea of having the media player played across activities? @Avi

Comment: if you want to use thread then create a Singlton class so you don't need to create the thread every time as you are having thread in BaseActivity so every time you launch a new activity new thread will be created.

Comment: But still the best approach is use service instead of thread.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the Singleton class? Also, how would I grab the context from a thread within a different class?

Comment: please find the code below in answer

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Class MediaManager created on 11/07/16 - 4:01 PM.
 * All copyrights reserved to the Zoomvy.
 * Class behaviour is to initialize and play a media file on notification
 */
public class MediaManager {
    /**
     * SingleTon instance
     */
    private static MediaManager sInstance;

    private Context mContext;

    private MediaManager(Context context) {
       mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static MediaManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (null == sInstance) {
            synchronized (MediaManager.class) {
                sInstance = new MediaManager(context);
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Above is the singleton class for the Media Manager. Here you can further define the media player and it will be single instance for all your activity.

[But still I recommend to use a service instead of a thread.](https://github.com/SueSmith/android-music-player/blob/master/src/com/example/musicplayer/MusicService.java)